# How would i do "Box entends Cube"

Tags: java

I want to extend a Cube from Box. My program has three parts first i do a rectangle class then i use it to extend a Box class then i extend a Cube. I am stuck at the Cube part. This is what my instructions say :

Assessment Instructions
a. A Cube is a Box where the length, width, and height all have the same values.
b. You won’t have to add any additional instance variables or methods, but you
will have to set up the Cube’s constructor to ensure that length, width, and
height all have the same values.

Rectangle:

```
    public class Rectangle
    {
        // instance variables 
        private int length;
        private int width;

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class rectangle
         */
        public Rectangle(int l, int w)
        {
            // initialise instance variables
            length = l;
            width = w;
        }

        // return the height
        public int getLength()
        {
            return length;
        }
        public int getWidth()
        {
            return width;
        }

    }
```

Box:

```
public class Box extends Rectangle
{
    // instance variables 
    private int height;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class box
     */
    public Box(int l, int w, int h)
    {
        // call superclass
        super(l, w);
        // initialise instance variables
        height = h;
    }

    // return the height
    public int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

}
```

And the main  one Cube:

```
class Cube extends Box{
    // instance variables 
    private int height;
        private int length;
    private int width;

    public Cube(int h,int w,int l){
        super(h,w,l);

    }

    public double getheight(){
        return height;

               }
        public double getlength() {
            return length;
        }

        public double getwidth() {
            return width;
        }
}
```

I need to know if I did the Cube one right or not. If i didn't do it right please help me fix it.

Comment: You duplicated everything from box. What's a cube, anyway? How is it different from a box?

Comment: I'll edit my code with what my instructions say.

Comment: So, the instructions say: "You won’t have to add any additional instance variables or methods." But you did. Why?

Comment: I don't think that a box should extend a rectangle. extends is used when the super class is similar to the child class. While A box is a 3d rectangle, it is definitely not a rectangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cube is a box with all sides equal.  So pass the same length parameter to all 3 dimensions of the box.

```
public class Cube extends Box{
    public Cube(int length)
    {
        super(length, length, length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public class Box extends Cube {`

Comment: I appreciate your humor

Answer (score 0):

rgettman already has the correct solution, but just to elaborate on it:  Cube extends from Box, so it inherits all of the (non-private) methods and all the members.  Technically it has all members but "private" members will not be visible or modifiable by the child.  You don't need to redeclare the methods in the child class unless you want to change its implemented behavior.

If a class is intended to be extended, the "protected" type is often used, as the children will be able to inherit the variable with visiblity to it.  It depends on if the child class will need to modify the member variable directly.